# How to store drop down selected value in variable on page load in php?

Tags: php, html

I have a drop downlist which has a selected value by default of **Small**. I want that when page loads that pre-selected value should be store in php variable.I have not submit button.

**HTML Part**

```
<form action="" method = "post">        
    <label style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; margin-top:8px; float:left; margin-right:40px;">Select Size: </label>
    <select class="styled" name="size" style="float:right; margin-right:80px;">
        <option value="Small" selected>Small</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Large">Large</option>
    </select>                          
</form>
```

**Php Part**

```
<?php
$selected_val='';
if( isset ( $_POST['size'] ) ) {
    $selected_val = $_POST['size'];
}
echo $selected_val;
?>
```

But When I echo **$selected_val** this gives me nothing. can anybody please point out that what's the error and how to do this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't store a php variable after the html is generated. PHP is server side language, and this is BEFORE html is generated. you have to use ajax to store a selected value to a php script.

Comment: Well, you are checking the POST variable, but you have not POSTed anything. Since you know that Small is what is going to be selected on load (as you have set that in your HTML), then you can just store it directly.

Comment: can you please give me some helping material or edit my code so that I carry out my work... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your complete solution you need to use AJAX to achieve your task that whenver you load your document it will automatically get the selected value

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>q</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="submitthis();">

<form action="" method = "post">

       <label style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; margin-top:8px; float:left; margin-right:40px;">Select Size: </label>
       <select onchange="submitthis();" id="sizes" class="styled" name="size" style="float:right; margin-right:80px;">
            <option value="Small" selected="">Small</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Large">Large</option>
        </select>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
 </form> 

<script>
function submitthis()
{
    var val = document.getElementById('sizes').value;
    console.log(val);
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","reply.php?size="+val,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}

    </script>
```

and you need to make another file in same folder where is that html file exists with name  reply.php and paste the following code

```
    <?php
        $selected_val='';
          if(isset($_GET['size'])){
            $selected_val = $_GET['size'];
        }
        echo $selected_val;
?>
```

i have made another small change that when you change the value from select box it will than load that crosponding value as well.